# Returning clicked layer leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I want to select a created polygon, created through [leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) by click.
This is how I implement `leaflet.draw`

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable   layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

// event when polygon is created
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  // add created polygon to Itemcollection
  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

  // add to map
  map.addLayer(layer);
});
```

I then want to know, onto which polygon I click. I do this with [each.layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer)

```
drawnItems.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.on('click', function() {
    console.log(this._leaflet_id);
  });
});
```

However, that never returns anything.
When I replace `drawnItems` with `map`

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.on('click', function() {
    console.log(this._leaflet_id);
  });
});
```

It works – sort of. It always returns the same `id` though, even if I click on different polygons... Where is the hickup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your click event listener on `drawnItems` group not displaying anything, this is probably because you loop through `drawnItems.eachLayer` **before** it is actually filled with your drawn features / polygons.

`eachLayer` will loop through the *current* child layers. It will not have any effect on layers that may be added later on.

You could rather directly attach your listener to your `drawnItems` Feature Group. In that case, you can access the child layer that triggered the event trough `event.layer` where `event` is the listener argument:

```js
drawnItems.on("click", function(event) {
    console.log("from drawnItems: " + event.layer._leaflet_id);
});
```

As for your listener on `map`, it displays always the same `id` due to the same original reason (`eachLayer` loops through *current* child layers, i.e. only `drawnItems` very probably in your case), and the fact that your `drawnItems` Feature Group also emits a `"click"` event. Therefore, you are actually seeing the `id` of your `drawnItems` each time.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/108/